# pgadmin - The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.news
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('news_id_seq'::regclass),
    name "char",
    CONSTRAINT news_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.news
    OWNER to postgres;
```

In pgadmin:

1. Right-click on table name
2. Select view-edit data -> all rows
3. I fill in empty fields.
4. I click on Execute/Refresh F5
5. The data are lost.

Next:

1. Right-click on table name
2. Select view-edit data -> all rows
3. I fill in empty fields.
4. Click on Floppy Disk - save
5. Data are saved.

It works good.

But:

1. Right-click on table name
2. Select Scripts -> INSERT Script
3. INSERT INTO public.news(
   id, name)
   VALUES (10, "name");
4. Click on Save - I have option to save on my computer...
5. Click on Execute:

   500 Internal Server Error

   ## Internal Server Error

   The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

If i use Query tool, I have the same error...

Why can not I use SQL queries in pgadmin? How to check what causes the error? Currently the error is general...

Comment: What is the exact version of your pgAdmin? Which OS do you use?

Comment: `name "char",` :: Why do you quote`char` ? (It is not an identifier)